# Oauth2 with Spring Security - UserRedirectRequiredException

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, spring-java-config

I want to implement OAuth2 in my web but I got this error when I try to do a request: `/facebook/info`

I was follow the official [guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) and I look [the examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2/tonr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples) but I still doing something is wrong, As the error said `A redirect is required to get the users approval` and I read somewhere (don't remember) that the redirect url is added by the filter I was thinking that isn't configured right... or the error comes from other place.

Config:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        registerProxyFilter(container, "oauth2ClientContextFilter");

        ...

        // Add filters
        private void registerProxyFilter(ServletContext servletContext, String name) {
            DelegatingFilterProxy filter = new DelegatingFilterProxy(name);
            filter.setContextAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher");
            servletContext.addFilter(name, filter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,
                false, "/*");
        }
    }

}
```

Add security filter:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
    AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

RestTemplate:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public OAuth2RestTemplate facebookRestTemplate() {
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(),
            oauth2Context);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
            MediaType.valueOf("text/javascript")));
    template.setMessageConverters(Arrays
            .<HttpMessageConverter<?>> asList(converter));
    return template;
}

@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails facebook() {
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    details.setId("facebook");
    details.setClientId("*****");
    details.setClientSecret("*****");
    details.setAccessTokenUri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
    details.setUserAuthorizationUri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth");
    details.setTokenName("oauth_token");
    details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
    details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
    return details;
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class FacebookController {

    @Autowired
    private RestOperations facebookRestTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/facebook/info")
    public String info(Model model) throws Exception {
        ObjectNode result = facebookRestTemplate.getForObject(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends", ObjectNode.class);
        ArrayNode data = (ArrayNode) result.get("data");
        ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (JsonNode dataNode : data) {
            friends.add(dataNode.get("name").asText());
        }
        model.addAttribute("friends", friends);
        return "facebook";
    }

    public void setFacebookRestTemplate(RestOperations facebookRestTemplate) {
        this.facebookRestTemplate = facebookRestTemplate;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
2015-08-28 22:10:34,595 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134)  :Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.test.commons.controllers.FacebookController.info(org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
2015-08-28 22:10:34,596 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134)  :Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.test.commons.controllers.FacebookController.info(org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
2015-08-28 22:10:34,597 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134)  :Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.test.commons.controllers.FacebookController.info(org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
2015-08-28 22:10:34,597 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134)  :Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.test.commons.controllers.FacebookController.info(org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
2015-08-28 22:10:34,597 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver (SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.java:249)  :Resolving to view 'error/error' for exception of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException], based on exception mapping [java.lang.RuntimeException]
2015-08-28 22:10:34,597 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver (SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.java:309)  :Applying HTTP status code 500
2015-08-28 22:10:34,598 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver (SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.java:341)  :Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
2015-08-28 22:10:34,604 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (DispatcherServlet.java:1198)  :Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error/error'; model is {exception=org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval}
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:347) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:194) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:565) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.getForObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.test.commons.controllers.FacebookController.info(FacebookController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:806) [jetty-servlet-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) [jetty-servlet-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:550) [jetty-security-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1128) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1062) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:507) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:237) [jetty-server-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:240) [jetty-io-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:93) [jetty-io-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53) [jetty-io-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceRun.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceRun.java:191) [jetty-util-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceRun.run(ExecuteProduceRun.java:126) [jetty-util-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:641) [jetty-util-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:559) [jetty-util-9.3.0.M2.jar:9.3.0.M2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice what the ExecptionResolver was making the problem, to solve it I exclude a exception.

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
        Properties exceptionMappings = new Properties();
        exceptionMappings.put(
                "com.test.commons.model.exceptions.NotFound", "error/404");
        exceptionMappings.put("java.lang.Exception", "error/error");
        exceptionMappings.put("java.lang.RuntimeException", "error/error");
        exceptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(exceptionMappings);
        Properties statusCodes = new Properties();
        statusCodes.put("error/404", "404");
        statusCodes.put("error/error", "500");
        exceptionResolver.setStatusCodes(statusCodes);
        // ADDED TO IGNORE THRE USER_REDIRECT_REQUIRED_EXCEPTION
        exceptionResolver
                .setExcludedExceptions(UserRedirectRequiredException.class);
        return exceptionResolver;
    }
```

I still getting the error, but now is redirected to a facebook page and not to a error page